# Recode Supervised Classification In ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have used Supervised classification technique in ArcGIS 10.1 software to generate of Land use/Land cover classification.

In my built-up class, it has been spread out into different other classes.

Now, I would like to recode it (just like in Erdas software).

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well and you have Spatial Analyst, you can use the [Reclassify tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm) to classify the target classes with the new values. If you do not have Spatial Analyst, then convert the raster image into vector shapefile (Polygon) and select the polygon that you need to update their class values into the new one. then convert it back to raster. Another option is to use open source (SAGA for example) to reclassify the raster image. You can refer to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188833/63384) on how to use SAGA to reclassify your image.