# Raster to polygon conversion losing data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-conversion

I'm trying to do a simple conversion with Raster to Polygon. However, as you can see in the picture below not all data (the area in orange) makes the transition. Raster to the left and polygon to the right.

[image: Raster to Polygon]

The RGB colors of the orange area is 255 222 183 compared to 255 251 205 for the yellow area. The raster is currently in TIFF format but I have also tried png with the same result. My version of ArcMap is 10.4.1.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: maybe the vector has an attribute with the color and you didn't categorize it accordingly to that values?

Comment: You mean, all of the data is there but the symbology of the shapefile doesn't reveal all of the shapes? That is unfortunately not the case.

Comment: yes, that's what i meant

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using 3 bands-raster data in RGB color not one band classified raster. The output conversion from raster to vector tool may not work well as you have noticed in your example. One possible solution is that you need to reclassify the raster data using [Reclassify tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) so that each color represent a class.

If you have a Spatial Analyst extension, you can use the [Reclassify tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) to classify the color coded areas using supoervised classification. Then you can convert the raster into vector using raster to vector tool.

If you don't have Spatial Analyst, then the other option is to use open source software (SAGA for example) to reclassify the raster image. You can refer to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188818/group-points-and-compute-area/188833#188833) on how to use SAGA to reclassify your image.